# Windows list-view control: Reliably retrieve width of first column

Tags: listview, winapi

I am using a list-view control (as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735(v=vs.85).aspx)), and I try to compute the rectangle of the intersection of some column and some list item.

I found `GetSubItemRect` (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1w31a26y.aspx)) which much has been written about already (e.g. [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?346930-GetSubItemRect()-does-not-work-as-expected-for-the-first-column-what-am-I-missing)). In particular, it uses a one-based index and works only for real "subitems", while calling it with "subitem index" `0` does not yield the rect of the first column, but the whole item's rectangle.

I *thought* all this would be no problem, since I could work around as follows:

```
RECT wholeItem;
GetItemRect(iItem, &wholeItem, LVIR_BOUNDS); // compute whole line
RECT subItem;
GetSubItemRect(iItem, 1, LVIR_BOUNDS, &subItem); // adjust right border to beginning of first subitem
wholeItem.right = subItem.left;
```

However, this approach apparently fails to deal with the case where the column of subitem 1 has a zero width. In this case `subItem` is a rect, whose components are all 0 (possibly generated via `SetRectEmpty`).

I think I can work around this problem by doing the following:

```
wholeItem.right = GetColumnWidth(0)
```

So, my questions are:

- Is the strange behaviour of GetSubItemRect somewhere documented?
- Is my way (using `GetColumnWidth`) reliable?

Comment: LVM_GETHEADER + HDM_GETITEMRECT

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks for your hint! Is your suggestion more reliable/preferrable to mine (which would be `LVM_GETCOLUMNWIDTH`)?

Comment: It should be exactly the same, LVM_GETCOLUMNWIDTH causes sending a message to header internally.

Comment: I would have expected LVM_GETCOLUMNWIDTH to be reliable but if you say it's not, try asking the header directly.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I think `GetSubItemRect` is not reliable, but I think `GetColumnWidth` resp. `LVM_GETCOLUMNWIDTH` is.